# Is it possible to move an object instance to different threads at different points of code in a QT project?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am trying to determine if you can move one object instance to different threads at different points during run-time.

Below is some sample code to show you what I mean:

```
this->thread1           = new QThread( this );
this->thread2           = new QThread( this );

this->pObject->moveToThread( this->thread1 );

connect(this->thread1, SIGNAL(started()), this->pObject, SLOT(fnc1()));
connect(this->thread2, SIGNAL(started()), this->pObject, SLOT(fnc2()));

this->thread1->start();

//after thread1 has finished

this->pObject->moveToThread( this->thread2 );
this->thread2->start();
```

Is it possible to do this?

Edit: After Kuba's advice on not using a direct connection and him pointing out I must be interfering with the event loop somehow, I realised manually terminating the threads was not a good idea. I am adding my termination of the threads here to show where I am going wrong and to try and find a better way of achieving the same result.

```
connect(this->pObject, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(stopThread()));

void Class::stopThread( void )
{
    if( this->thread1->isRunning() )
    {
        this->thread1->terminate();
        return;
    }

    if( this->thread2->isRunning() )
    {
        this->thread2->terminate();
        this->pObject->moveToThread( this->thread1 );
    }
}

void Object::fnc1( void )
{
    /*Does some work..*/

    finished(); //Calls 'finished' to signal stopThread when done (not stopping on its own)
}
```

*ADDITIONAL INFO*
I have MainClass which holds the instances to both thread1, thread2 and pObject (pointer to the object I am trying to move from thread1 to thread2 and back again if necessary).

Main class constructor:

```
MainClass::MainClass( QWidget *parent ) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->ui.setupUi(this);

    this->thread1           = new QThread( this );
    this->thread2           = new QThread( this );

    this->pObject->moveToThread( this->thread1 );

    connect( this->pObject, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(stopThread()) );
    connect( this->thread1, SIGNAL(started()), this->pObject, SLOT(fnc1()) );
    connect( this->thread2, SIGNAL(started()), this->pObject, SLOT(fnc2()) );   
}
```

Slot for when menu item is clicked:

```
void MainClass::on_action_call_fnc1_triggered( void )
{
    if( this->thread1->isRunning() )
        return;

    /*EXECUTES SOME CLASSIFIED CODE THAT CANNOT BE SHOWN*/

    this->thread1->start();//should trigger fnc1 execution
}
```

fnc1 held in Object class that is called when thread1 starts:

```
void Object::fnc1( void )
{
    /*DOES SOME MORE SECRET PROCESSING THAT CANNOT BE SHOWN*/
    this->finished(); // triggers MainClass::stopThread( void )
}
```

Slot for when menu item is clicked to start fnc2 executing:

```
void MainClass::on_action_call_fnc2_triggered( void )
{
    if( this->thread1->isRunning() || this->thread2->isRunning() )
        return;

    this->pObject->moveToThread( this->thread2 );
    this->thread2->start();//should trigger fnc2 execution
}
```

fnc2 held in Object:

```
void Object::fnc2( void )
{
   /*DOES SOME MORE SECRET PROCESSING THAT CANNOT BE SHOWN*/
    this->finished(); // triggers MainClass::stopThread( void )
}
```

stopThread function:

```
void MainClass::stopThread( void )
{
    if( this->thread1->isRunning() )
    {
        /*this->thread1->quit();
        this->thread1->exit();*/
        this->thread1->terminate();
        //this->thread1->wait( 0 ); //Trying different ways of stopping the thread
        return;
    }

    if( this->thread2->isRunning() )
    {
        this->thread2->terminate();
        //this->thread2->quit(); // Trying different ways of stopping the thread
        //this->thread2->exit();
        this->pObject->moveToThread( this->thread1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you compile and run it?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Memory is shared between *all* threads, so an object cannot be "moved" to a single thread.

Comment: fnc1 is called and completes fine, then I call this->thread2->start(); and it doesn't signal fnc2. o11c, I believe QT have implemented this in a different way to the norm, which is why I held your reaction at first, but with trying to learn QT I have accepted this is how it is done using their framework

Comment: You can move an object from one thread to another but... `moveToThread` *must* be called from the thread on which the objects events are being processed (if I remember correctly).

Comment: from the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread), *the current thread must be same as the current thread affinity. In other words, this function can only "push" an object from the current thread to another thread, it cannot "pull" an object from any arbitrary thread to the current thread.*

Comment: This means that after you have first  called `moveToThread` and the object moved to thread1, you cannot call `moveToThread` from the main thread. . .

Comment: @Mike You can, but only after `thread1` is finished. At that point `object` is threadless (`object->thread() == nullptr`) and half-functional, and any thread can take its ownership, so you should be moving it somewhere pronto anyway (or destructing it) in most cases.

Comment: Okay thank you all

Comment: After a terminate, your entire process can end up in a corrupt state, so all you can do at that point is to abort() or exit() as quickly as you can. You do not want to terminate a thread, really. Simply `{quit(); wait()}` the thread instead.

Comment: @KubaOber , thanks for explaining this, just to make things clear, by *half-functional* do you mean that all queued connections will cease to work? Also I can't find anything in the documentation regarding what happens to `QObject`s when the `QThread` they are living in finishes. Am I missing something?

Comment: Event delivery doesn't work - it can't because an object without a thread has no event loop servicing it. Thus timers don't work, *incoming* queued slot/functor calls don't work, `deleteLater` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, but you have to assert that the object's thread is indeed finished:

```
Q_ASSERT(pObject->thread() == nullptr);
pObject->moveToThread(thread2);
```

When `thread1` is finished, the object's thread becomes null and only then you're allowed to move it to another thread from arbitrary thread. Otherwise, if object's thread is not finished yet, you could only move the object from its thread:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, pObject, [this]{ pObject->moveToThread(thread2); }
```

Comment: Your answer coupled with adding 'Qt::DirectConnection' argument in the 'connect' calls worked. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeO You definitely do *not* want to use a direct connection, because the sender and the receiver are in different threads. Specifically, `fnc1` and `fnc2` won't be called in `thread1` nor `thread2`. You can easily test that: at beginning of either `fnc`, assert the correct thread: `void fnc1() { Q_ASSERT(thread() == QThread::currentThread()); ... }`. That assertion will fail with direct connection, by design. **You're doing something else wrong, like blocking the event loop in thread1 or 2.**

Comment: I am manually terminating both threads after the function call finishes as they do not appear to terminate by themselves, so I guess this is why the second thread will not work without a direct connection. I will update my main post to show the termination. I will remove the direct connection and find out a better way to get the thread to end.